# Java HashMap to Matrix

Tags: java, open-source, hashmap, metrics

I am facing a problem. I used the following hashmap to store some values

```
HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

The object is another HashMap (yeah, you can say HashMap of HashMap). String is to store book name, and Object is again another hashmap that is to store author name and number of authors. So it can look like ( Xyz book{authname,numberOfAuthors} ). Now I want to print this hashmap as NxN matrix. Is there any default function out there that i can use for this? If no, then anybody can tell me any hint to do it in easy way? Because I do not want to use so many loops and if conditions (it will kill system).

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to write the hashmap structure but as i pressed submit button. There isn't anything about the code statement i wrote :(. May be it does not allow to write code.

Comment: When you write code, you need to mark it and hit the `101010` button to encode it!

Comment: That, or manually indent all code by at least 4 spaces.

Comment: 1.) did you mean "matrix" as in "a grid of values" instead of "metrices"?
2.) Why do you use a HashMap to store information about the book instead of a custom class, for example one called "Book"?

Comment: @Joachim: I'm pretty sure he means "matrices" - actually, only one matrix. But I refrained from editing because I thought he might be editing too.

Comment: How do you store multiple authors?

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for quick reply. Yes i want to store in one matrix ( if there is good solution with grid, I can use that too). 
@Thilo: I made a custom class ( BookInfo ) that i am using to store the data and multiple authors.

Comment: What are going to be your columns then? One row per book, one column per author? Or one row per book, one column "title", one column "authors" (all in one), and so on?

Comment: Thanks Thilo, My row would be book names, Columns would be author names, cell will have some numerical values. Each numerical values is a code for the author for that specific book.

Comment: Also can you please tell me? How can I format hashmap object values? It is returning as {abc,123}

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you underused the OO potential ... You can create your own `Book` class and override the `toString()` to print all the fields ...

```
public class Book{
    private String bookName;
    private String authorName;
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s written by %s",bookName,authorName);
    }
}
```

by this way your library will be something like :

```
Map<String, Book> myLibrary = new HashMap<String, Book>(...);
```

and to print all your library you will need a simple loop :

```
    for(Book b : myLibrary.values()) {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely no built-in function to do this.

The first thing you need to do is to figure out the unique keys in your second-level map and assign them to columns. Maybe you already know them (if they are fixed), otherwise you have to loop over all of them once and collect them in a set.

If you do have fixed keys, you should consider eliminating the second-level map, and using a Java bean class for this (the books).

If you are really going to print the matrix, you need to think about formatting, mainly column widths. Again, this can also be fixed a priori, or you can look at the data (all or sample) to figure it out.

Ignoring formatting for a moment, you can output something like CSV by then looping over
the map (ideally in sorted key order), and output one line for each entry (book). In each line, you would then loop over the columns (the key list) and output each field.

Comment: ...and the loops and conditions can't possibly "kill the system".  Write it as @Thilo suggests and only then, if you see performance problems, start to worry about performance.  Even if there were a built-in way, that way would be using the same loops and conditions internally, so performance would be roughly identical to the obvious hand-rolled approach.